# Shell Script: How i can list trough cli of virtualbox the vms and delete all but one called "SaveThisOne"?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, virtualbox

Shell Script: How i can list trough cli of virtualbox the vms and delete all but one called "SaveThisOne"?

CAUTION: The lines below deletes all virtualbox vms:

```bash
VBoxManage list runningvms | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs -I vmid VBoxManage controlvm vmid poweroff
VBoxManage list vms | awk '{print $2;}' | xargs -I vmid VBoxManage unregistervm --delete vmid
```

**Possible solution**, after the help of the guys here, pmf, BeatOne and tripleee what i did was:

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script list all VM's through virtualbox cli, vboxmanage, do poweroff and deletes the virtual machines case they don't are listed in $vmnames variable.
# list all VM's
vboxmanage list vms |
awk -F '"' '{print $2}' |
while read -r vmnames; do
    case $vmnames in
      "Win10" | "Ubuntu" | "YourVMNameToSave" ) continue;; 
    esac 
    # poweroff and delete case name is not listed in $vmnames variable as a string. 
    vboxmanage controlvm "$vmnames" poweroff
    vboxmanage unregistervm "$vmnames"  --delete
done
```

Comment: Add a condition to your `awk` command, so it executes only if the name doesn't match, "swallowing" the one to be saved.

Comment: I would help us greatly if you show the output of `VBoxManage list vms` and `VBoxManage list runningvms`

Comment: Hello pmf! If you have some time, could you give me a code example with the exception of the vm named "SaveThisOne"?

Comment: @RafaelTics I don't know what's the output of VBoxManage, and what exactly is in column 2 (or the other columns), but my suggestion went something along the lines of `awk '$2 != "SaveThisOne" {print $2;}'`

Comment: I rolled back your changes. Your question should remain strictly a question; ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: **Again,** please don't edit the question into an answer. I have updated the duplicate list to include one with the `case` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the output of `vmboxmanage list vms` looks like this:

```
"SaveThisOne" {asdgfdasg}
"DeleteThis" {asdfasdfasdg}
"AndThis" {gasdfas}
"AndThisToo" {asdfas}
```

Here is an Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# list all VMs
vms=$(vboxmanage list vms)

# Check every vm
while read -r line; do
    # Get VM name
    vm_name=$(echo "$line" | awk -F'"' '{print $2}')
    echo $vm_name

    # check name and delete
    if [ "$vm_name" != "SaveThisOne" ]; then
        # delete if name not like 
        vboxmanage unregistervm "$vm_name" --delete
    fi
done <<< "$vms"
```

i think that should do the job, but i have not tested it, so be careful

Comment: Saving the result into a variable just to use that variable exactly once to feed the `while read -r` loop is just a waste of memory.  You want `vboxmanage list vms | while read -r line` (though you could factor out the Awk by doing `while read -r image junk`, except you'll still have to get rid of the quotes)

Comment: Perhaps a better solution is `vboxmanage list vms | awk -F '"' '{print $2}' | while read -r image; do case $image in "SaveThisOne" | "AnotherOneIWant" ) continue;; esac ... done`

Comment: Thank 's for the insight @tripleee about memory waste. Now i'm searching for a solution inside the script crafted by BeatONE. A solution that accepts more than "one vm" to save from exclusion. Like it was pointed, i have created other question about it. If you could help, i'll appreciate.

Comment: The previous comment already contains a solution for that. I'm out of close votes so I just left a comment on the new question. Going forward, please search before asking.

Comment: @triplee 0k. I'll just update this question with a possible solution, thank's for the help.

Comment: @tripleee is right. I just made this quickly on the side and didn't think about memory. 

Would be cool if you could mark this as a solution if it got you going in the right direction ✌️